# Как получить значение в файле Json?

Tags: python, json

Есть код:

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = "https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5&station=s2014001&transport_types=train&direction=departure&date=2021-01-15"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = json.loads(r.text)
for train in trains["schedule"]:
    print(f"Отправка в {train['departure']}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")
```

я не знаю как получить название станции. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
    print(f"[trains['schedule']['station']['title']]")
```

Но выдает ошибку **KeyError: 'schedule'**
Не понимаю, что не так.
Вот весь Json:

```
{'date': '2021-01-15',
 'event': 'departure',
 'interval_schedule': [],
 'pagination': {'limit': 100, 'offset': 0, 'total': 15},
 'schedule': [{'arrival': '2021-01-14T23:22:00+03:00',
               'days': '13, 15, 17, 19\xa0января, 29\xa0марта, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, '
                       '29\xa0апреля, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17\xa0мая, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T00:28:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '382С',
                          'short_title': 'Грозный — Москва',
                          'title': 'Грозный — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '382S_6_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T00:20:00+03:00',
               'days': '13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\xa0января, 2, '
                       '4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\xa0февраля, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T02:00:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '123Н',
                          'short_title': 'Новосибирск — Белгород',
                          'title': 'Новосибирск — Белгород',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '123N_14_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T04:35:00+03:00',
               'days': '15\xa0января, 21\xa0февраля, 11, 28, 29, 30\xa0апреля, '
                       '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14\xa0мая, '
                       '…',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T05:20:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '306М',
                          'short_title': 'Москва — Сухум',
                          'title': 'Москва — Сухум',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '306M_2_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T06:48:00+03:00',
               'days': 'ежедневно по 15.01',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T07:23:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '034С',
                          'short_title': 'Москва — Владикавказ',
                          'title': 'Москва — Владикавказ',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '034S_1_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': None,
               'days': 'ежедневно',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T07:33:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '737Ж',
                          'short_title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '737ZH_4_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T07:12:00+03:00',
               'days': '15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\xa0января, 3, 5, 7, '
                       '9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23\xa0февраля, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T07:55:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '146Э',
                          'short_title': 'Москва — Назрань',
                          'title': 'Москва — Назрань',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '146YE_4_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T09:18:00+03:00',
               'days': 'только 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15\xa0января',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T09:58:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '109В',
                          'short_title': 'Москва — Анапа',
                          'title': 'Москва — Анапа',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '109V_1_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T12:14:00+03:00',
               'days': '14, 15, 16, 17, 18\xa0января, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, '
                       '17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25\xa0февраля, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T12:55:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '035А',
                          'short_title': 'Санкт-Петербург — Адлер',
                          'title': 'Санкт-Петербург — Адлер',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '035A_0_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T14:18:00+03:00',
               'days': 'только 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19\xa0января, 12, 13\xa0'
                       'февраля',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T14:57:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '036С',
                          'short_title': 'Адлер — Санкт-Петербург',
                          'title': 'Адлер — Санкт-Петербург',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '036S_4_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': None,
               'days': 'ежедневно',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T16:21:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '739Ж',
                          'short_title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '739ZH_1_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T17:10:00+03:00',
               'days': 'только 11, 15, 17\xa0января',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T18:20:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 63438,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'Гранд Сервис Экспресс '
                                               '(Таврия)'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '374С',
                          'short_title': 'Симферополь — Смоленск',
                          'title': 'Симферополь — Смоленск',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '374S_1_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': None,
               'days': '15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 24, 28, 31\xa0января, 4, 7, '
                       '11, 14, 18, 21, 25, 28\xa0февраля, 4, 7, 11\xa0марта, '
                       '…',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T20:30:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '025В',
                          'short_title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'title': 'Воронеж — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '025V_2_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T20:06:00+03:00',
               'days': 'ежедневно по 15.01',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T20:55:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '033С',
                          'short_title': 'Владикавказ — Москва',
                          'title': 'Владикавказ — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '033S_12_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-15T20:46:00+03:00',
               'days': '15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\xa0января, 2, 5, 7, '
                       '9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23\xa0февраля, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-15T21:28:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '145С',
                          'short_title': 'Назрань — Москва',
                          'title': 'Назрань — Москва',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '145S_7_2',
                          'vehicle': None}},
              {'arrival': '2021-01-16T01:24:00+03:00',
               'days': '16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30\xa0января, 1, 4, 6, 8, '
                       '10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24\xa0февраля, …',
               'departure': '2021-01-16T02:09:00+03:00',
               'except_days': None,
               'is_fuzzy': False,
               'platform': '',
               'stops': '',
               'terminal': None,
               'thread': {'carrier': {'code': 112,
                                      'codes': {'iata': None,
                                                'icao': None,
                                                'sirena': None},
                                      'title': 'РЖД/ФПК'},
                          'express_type': None,
                          'number': '382Я',
                          'short_title': 'Москва — Грозный',
                          'title': 'Москва — Грозный',
                          'transport_subtype': {'code': None,
                                                'color': None,
                                                'title': None},
                          'transport_type': 'train',
                          'uid': '382YA_10_2',
                          'vehicle': None}}],
 'station': {'code': 's2014001',
             'popular_title': '',
             'short_title': '',
             'station_type': 'station',
             'station_type_name': 'станция',
             'title': 'Воронеж-1',
             'transport_type': 'train',
             'type': 'station'}}
PS C:\Users\Vladik\Desktop\Bot_info>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`station` в `json` лежит на том же верхнем уровне, что и `schedule`, а не внутри него:

```
print(f"{trains['station']['title']}")
```

Вывод:

```
Воронеж-1
```